# Jqeury datatable to retrieve SharePoint list items

Tags: custom-list, datatable

I am trying to build Jquery datatable to retrieve the list items depending on two filer dropdown boxes and a button. I have a custom list with Title, District, Organization, Number of Tasks as columns.

Organization and District are Drop Down boxes, upon selection of Organization drop down value district values should show up and then we hit button to retrieve the results in datatable. Please check the screen shot below for what I am looking for. Suggestions on this please.[image]

Comment: In the `click` event of your `GetData` button, call the [jquery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to call the corresponding [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints) to return your items and in the `success method` fill the table rows using [jquery html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Is this a question more about how to use JQuery datatables or specifically how to query the SP REST APIs?

Comment: Robert its about how to query the SP REST APIs using jquery